# JSONP executes error block while making an ajax call during page load even though the status is 200 OK

Tags: java, jquery

During page load JSONP executes error block  while making an ajax call even though the status is 200 OK and the error text is "parseerror". But the same ajax call executes success block when it is called on some click event from UI.

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain : true,

    type : "GET",

    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback : 'success',
    url : "rest/getRecommendation",
    cache: false,
    timeout : 15000,
    then : function(data) {

    },
    error : function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

Comment: Please reformat your question. I tried to but seems you miss some code.

Comment: $jq.ajax({
           crossDomain : true,
     type : "GET",
     contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType : "jsonp",
     jsonpCallback : 'success',
     url : "rest/getRecommendationforPortal",
     cache: false,
     timeout : 15000,
     then : function(data) {
      //alert("failed to get data in recoLoad()-- in then");
     },

Comment: Please edit your question with your code.

Comment: $jq.ajax({
                crossDomain : true,

                type : "GET",

                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType : "jsonp",

                jsonpCallback : 'success',
                url : "rest/getRecommendation",
                cache: false,
                timeout : 15000,
                then : function(data) {


                },

Comment: @user3779242 You are able to edit your question if you need to make updates. Posting code in the comments isn't such a great idea as you can't format it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have editted my question and repost the same.